# This does not toggle correctly

Tags: jquery

Why does this not toggle correctly?

```
$('#violation_form label').click(function() {
    //alert($(this).parent().prev().html());
    var $checkbox = $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    console.log(!$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SEkTp/2/

Comment: there is no `li` in the html - also use .prop() instead of .attr()

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BE9z3/1

Comment: There's no LI, jQuery is not defined, `prop` is better than `attr` here... Really, why hurry with posting a question THAT much?

Comment: My Good sir I beg you to look at the link again. I have corrected the previous deformities

Comment: @GeorgeNewton because you need to use .prop() insread of .attr() - see the fiddle I posted above

Comment: also you can try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BE9z3/3/

Comment: This might be offtopic, as I don't know what else you're doing with jQuery, but you don't need it for what it looks like you're doing, and you could just do this http://jsfiddle.net/SEkTp/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing `<label>` element. There's no point doing magic tricks to make clicking it affect the corresponding `<input>` when you can do it directly. Quoting the docs ([**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)):

> **The HTML `<label>` Element** represents a caption for an item in a user
>   interface. It can be associated with a control either by *placing the
>   control element inside the label element*, or by using the `for`
>   attribute. Such a control is called the *labeled control* of the label
>   element.

So both...

```
<label><input type="checkbox" />Whatever</label>
```

... and, more complex, but more flexible:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="some_checkbox" id="some_checkbox" />
<label for="some_checkbox">Whatever it is</label>
```

... will work.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xZGU/).

Comment: omg yes dis is so much simplerah!

Comment: Didn't realise you could wrap the label around the element and forego the use of `for`, does it reliably work like that? No docs I've looked at have mentioned doing it that way.

Comment: @MLeFevre Why, I considered that to be a well-known feature. Just added the quote from MDN, though. )

Answer (score 1):

There is no `li` element in the DOM. Also use `prop` to set checkboxes on/off. Try this:

```
    $('#violation_form label').click(function() {
    $checkbox = $(this).closest('form').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    console.log(!$checkbox.attr('checked'));
    $checkbox.prop("checked", !$checkbox.prop("checked"));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SEkTp/8/)**

Comment: Why use prop instead of attr?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/1719752

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** instead of `.attr()` to set the checked state of your checkbox:

```
$checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
```

Final code look like:

```
$('#violation_form label').click(function () {
    //alert($(this).parent().prev().html());
    var $checkbox = $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    console.log(!$checkbox.prop('checked'));
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEkTp/15/)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this => http://jsfiddle.net/SEkTp/14/

```
jQuery('#violation_form label').click(function() {
   // alert("hi");
    //alert($(this).parent().prev().html());
    var checkbox = jQuery(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    console.log(!checkbox.attr('checked'));
    checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one, You missed `<li>` in that structure. Now it's working fine

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SEkTp/12/)